# Executing a new SQL query while still looping through another one in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I found it hard to put this problem into words so I hope I didn't overlook too many earlier solutions to this! I'm looping through a table called weeks, like so:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM `Weeks` WHERE `periodid`=$periodid";
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $weekid = $row["weekid"];
}
```

Then, within the while loop, I want to retrieve all tasks from a table Tasks that share that week ID. So, I want to start a new SQL query within the while loop, but I think that interferes with the one used to run the while loop. How should I avoid this?

Comment: as long as you don't use the same var-names (`$result``, `$row`) there's nothing wrong with it. But a joined select might be a better option?

Comment: I thought that changing the variable names would make it work, but even when I only add a new $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM `tasks`" everything stops working. Would you know why that's happening?

Comment: please show the complete code of what you've tried and describe what 'stops to work' how!

Comment: I made a mistake Jeff, your suggestion of different variable names did the trick! Thanks a lot